# What is the problem with reassignment here?

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I'm designing a system to implement sets in C++, by keeping them stored in a vectored ordered in ascending order.

in my main, I'm maintaining another vector that stores all the sets.

```
int main() {
    vector <SET> vecSETS;
    int size = 0;
    SET set, set2;
    int func, setname1, setname2, data;
    SET emptyset = SET();
    

    while(cin >> func) {
        set.print();
        switch(func) {
        case 1:
            cin >> setname1 >> data;
            if (setname1 == vecSETS.size()) {
                cout << "yes"<< endl;
                vecSETS.push_back(emptyset);
            }
            set = vecSETS[setname1]; //this line
            cout << "h";
            set.print();
            set.insert(data);
            set.print();
            break;
```

when I'm reassiging the set variable acc to the set I want to operate on, it clears it. I'm guessing it has to do with how it stores it, and that I should clear it somewhere but I can't figure out why and how.

I was initially using a vector of pointers, and used the new keyword to go about things, but that was causing every set I operated on to operate on every set, so every set had the same elements, even though their pointers were different.

I switched to using this, but now the sets are getting cleared.

my class elements that matter if it helps:

```
class SET {
    public:
    vector<int> set;

    SET(int * set_array, int length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            set.push_back(set_array[i]);
        }
    };

    SET() {
    };

    int bin_search(int data) {
        int L = 0, N = set.size() - 1;
        int M = (L + N)/2;
        while (N > L+1) {
            
            if (data == set[M]) {
                return M;
            } else if (data > set[M]) {
                L = M;
                M = (L + N)/2;
            } else {
                N = M;
                M = (L + N)/2;
            }
        }
        if (data == set[N]) {
            return N;
        }
        if (data > set[N]) {
            return -1*(N+2);
        }
        if (data > set[L]) {
            return -1*(L+2);
        } else {
            return -1*(L+1);
        }

    };
    void insert(int data) {
        if (set.size() == 0) {
            set.push_back(data);
            cout << 1 << endl;
            cout << "this is a test" << endl;
            return;
        }
        int index = bin_search(data);
        if (index < 0) {
            index = abs(index) -1;
            set.emplace(set.begin() + index, data);
        } 
        cout << set.size() << endl;
    }
```

Comment: `vecSETS[setname1].insert(data);`. Don't copy the set.

Comment: Please note that the definition `SET emptyset = SET();` is the equivalent to `SET emptyset;`.

Comment: why though? what is the problem with reassignment?

Comment: @SamarthGoyal There is nothing in your code that ever puts a non-empty set into your vector. This is literally the only line of code that changes the vector `vecSETS.push_back(emptyset);`

Comment: I would not recommend naming a class in all caps, since all caps is commonly used for macros. Also, your class has a *public* data member `set`. Typically, data members of classes are private.

Comment: @SamarthGoyal I think you have the common beginner misunderstanding that in C++ objects are automatically references. You think that modifying `set` will modify the vector. But it's not true, in C++ if you want one variable to refer to some other location you have to be explicit about it.

Comment: @SamarthGoyal FYI -- `bin_search(data);` -- Are you aware of [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) that does the binary search?  Your method is flawed in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the assignment

```
set = vecSETS[setname1];
```

Here you create a ***copy*** of the set.

When you modify the copy with `insert`, you only modify the copy, not the original set in the vector.

You need to modify the same set, which can be done as suggested by molbdnilo in a comment to your question:

```
vecSETS[setname1].insert(data);
```

Or by using a *reference* to the actual set:

```
SET& set = vecSETS[setname1];
set.insert(data);
```

---

There's also another alternative: To copy the changed set back into the set in the vector:

```
set = vecSETS[setname1];
set.insert(data);
vecSETS[setname1] = set;
```

It's not a solution I recommend though.

If you need to do more than one operation on the set, use a reference. Otherwise use the set inside the vector directly.

Comment: doesn't SET& make it the wrong type? I'm getting errors;
sorry but have not used it like this ever

Comment: @SamarthGoyal It makes it a different type (a reference to a SET) but it doesn't seem to make it the wrong type. If you want help with errors then you really have to say what those errors are.

Comment: @SamarthGoyal It makes `set` an _alias_ of vecSETS[setname1]`, in effect.  In other words, they both refer to the same thing.

Comment: @SamarthGoyal The error might be because you define a variable inside a `case`. Use curly-braces `{}` to put all the code in the case in a separate statement block, and you can define new variables.